# statistics range rule of thumb confidence interval

Tags: statistics, means, confidence-interval

Suppose that the minimum and maximum ages for typical textbooks currently used in college courses are 0 and 8 years. Use the range rule of thumb to estimate the standard deviation.

Standard deviation = I have gotten max - min / 4

```
               = 8 - 0 / 4 

               = 2
```

Find the size of the sample required to estimage the mean age of textbooks currently used in college courses. Assume that you want 98% confidence that the sample mean is within 0.4 year of the population mean.

Required sample size =

I have no clue how to get the required sample size

What are the correct answers?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now can apply *Central Limit theorem* if n is large enough. The thumb rule is $n>30$. We will see if it is the case. The width of the confidence interval is

$$\overline X+ z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}-\left(\overline X- z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}\right)=2\cdot z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}$$

$\alpha$ is the significance level. Here it is $1-0.98=0.02$

$2\cdot z_{0.99}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}=0.4$

$2\cdot 2.33\cdot \frac{2}{\sqrt n}=0.4$

$\sqrt n=2\cdot 2.33\cdot \frac{2}{0.4}$

Comment: Hi, I have gotten the answer 23.3 for sqrt n sample size.

I sqrt 23.3 for 4.827007354 

I have entered both 23.3 and 4.827007354 but got them both wrong, I am not sure where there might be an error

Comment: @Alexis $\sqrt{n}=23.3$ Now you have to square both sides. $n=542.89$. Rounding up the value, because the textbooks can´t be divided. $n^*=543$. The good thing is, that $n^*$ is much larger than 30. Consequently the Central Limit Theorem can be applied.

Comment: Hmm I still got it wrong, your answer seems right though! I've added an edited photo above, I'm still trying to decipher what might be off...

Comment: Maybe you have to use more decimal places for the z-value. $\sqrt n=2\cdot 2.326\cdot \frac{2}{0.4} \Rightarrow n=541.028$. So it can be $541$ or maybe $542$. I hope it works.

Comment: Oh yeah by the way, where did 2 in "2⋅z 0.99⋅  s/√n =0.4" come from? 2 is the sample mean?

Comment: @Alexis Have you got the right answer ? If yes, I couldn´t believe it. Wait a minute for the explanation of "2"

Comment: Oh, I was going to double check with a peer and possibly even the professor before I submit but it looks right, I just gotta make sure!

Comment: @Alexis Let´s hope the best. //  You have to simplify the expression $\overline X+ z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}-\left(\overline X- z_{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}\cdot \frac{s}{\sqrt n}\right)$ What do you get ? Explanation: It is the difference of the upper limit and the lower limit of the confidence interval.

Comment: I got 137. something as the answer, I used a formula that was provided by the instructor and got it right, but I'll give you the checkmark anyways! Thanks again!